# Loading multiple IDB files for debugging session

Tags: ida

I can't seem to figure out if I can and how you load multiple idb files with notes into a debugging session?

Is there a method or plugin that allows me to load these idb's? What I am doing now is start the program make a memory snapshot and make notes that way. When I start the new debuggin session I rebase the dlls.

This does really not work well ;)

note, I currently only have IDA Basic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDA can only work with one IDB at a time. You'll need to either work with all modules in one IDB, or use serveral IDBs/IDA instances and detach/attach to the process as necessary.

Comment: It's not "minor", it would require a major reworking of IDA's architecture, so don't hold your breath.

Comment: I ment a minor request, not that this would be a minor issue ;)

I won't hold my breath and try to work with the memory snapshot method.